# Correct way to retrieve data from a webapi2.1 header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created a base api controller that allows me to access data from the header.

```
  public virtual int GetHeaderData()
    {
        if (Request != null)
        {
            var headers = Request.Headers;
            int customValue;
            if (headers.Contains("mycustomvalue"))
            {
                int.TryParse(headers.GetValues("mycustomvalue").First(), out customValue);
                return customValue;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

So calling this is pretty easy from any controller e.g. GetHeaderData()

However, to me this seems very difficult to unit test as the helper requires

> Request.Headers

Should I really be trying to read the header value at the controller level or should I be doing it somewhere else that will make this easier to test?

I am looking for a little advise on the best way I should be doing the above.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't go so far to call this an advice but just a suggestion for you to consider. First of all, unit testing should not determine your class design. It is possible to set the request object at controller level so that `Request.Headers` return the headers correctly for you to unit test. However, if I ask myself the question do this method belong in the controller, the answer is no, regardless of the desire to unit test or not. If I were to do this, I would much rather create an extension method for `HttpRequestMessage`. Extension method is just syntactic sugar but it is fundamentally a static helper method and I can use the extension method anywhere - controller, message handler, filter and so on. And then, I can unit test if I want.